# paypal Express Checkout: delivery address

Tags: paypal

I want to allow customers to pay with paypal without having to create a paypal account. Paypal allows this by setting 2 variables:

1. `SOLUTIONTYPE = 'Sole';`
2. `LANDINGPAGE = 'Billing';`

This takes the customer to a page where he can enter his details and pay. Creating a paypal account is optional.

Does anybody know a way to not have to ask for delivery address? Just enter the CC details and that is it?

I tried:

```
NOSHIPPING = 1
```

`REQCONFIRMSHIPPING = 0` (and not setting it at all)
`ADDROVERRIDE = all values` (and not setting it at all)

Any way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with Payments Basic and you certainly can't do it inside API Express Checkout (which is ONLY for Paypal accounts). You really need the flexibility of an API to do it. Have you considered Payments Pro or [Stripe](https://stripe.com/)?

Comment: I am trying to use Paypal alone, so customers do not have to pay for a certificate/insurance/fixed ip. I have already used omnipay to have payments with CC.

Comment: Payments Pro would be the way to go. Can run your own credit card transactions directly https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro

Comment: Yes, I know that part :) I already have that implemented for some customers but it requires an SSL connection. I am trying to get around those requirements and I am hoping to make it work like this. This is for really, really tight budget clients.